# Allow access for unathenticated users to specific page using ASP.Net Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using ASP.Net Forms Authentication. My Web.config looks like this.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

So currently every aspx page requires authentication.

I want to allow access to even unauthenticated users to a specific page named special.aspx.
How can I do this?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 60):

Take a look at the example on [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this 
application except for those that you have not explicitly 
specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated 
user access to the ThePageThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit.aspx 
page only. It is located in the same folder 
as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="ThePageThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated 
user access to all of the files that are stored 
in the TheDirectoryThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit folder.  -->
        <location path="TheDirectoryThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When using this technique for `<authentication mode="Windows" />` it allows the unauthenticated user access to the specific page I want it to ("yay"), but it still prompts for their credentials? You can close it and view the page just fine, but I'm wondering how to disable the "Authentication Required" for the specific page?

Comment: @TrevorNestman are you loading other assets on the page such as images etc? It's probably that they are prompting for the authentication.

Comment: @dnolan thanks for the response. I was able to figure it out. I asking what role they were in within the view, so I'm pretty sure that's what was prompting it.

Comment: @TrevorNestman Did you get the page to not prompt for credentials?  I have to keep windows authentication enabled in IIS because i need to get the users name, but I can't stop a particular page from prompting for credentials.  What did you change?

Comment: @glitzsfa I'm pretty sure I solved it through settings in the web.config. I no longer work for the company that needed this, so I can't dig it up either. Sorry

Answer (score 22):

Put the following in your web.config:

```
  <location path="special.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<location path="register.aspx"> //path here is path to your register.aspx page 
<system.web>

<authorization>
<allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx
</authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```

> **For more detail follow the below link**
>
> http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Answer (score 1):

**Allow everyone to access a particular page**

Sometimes you want to allow public access to some page and want to restrict access to rest of the site only to logged / authenticated users .i.e. do not allow anonymous access. Say your special.aspx is in your site's root folder. In the web.config of your website's root folder you need to have following setup.

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms"/>

       <authorization> <deny users="?"/>  //this will restrict anonymous user access
       </authorization>

   </system.web>
   <location path="special.aspx"> //path here is path to your special.aspx page 
   <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to special.aspx

 </authorization>
 </system.web>
 </location>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: To add to this, the position of the tag relative to the authentication tag is important. It must be placed after or else it won't work.