# ASP.NET - stop redirect to login page if coming from registration page

Tags: asp.net

Hopefully this is simple.  I have a fairly simple ASP.NET (framework version 2) app that uses a custom table for user validation.  Anyway I have two pages, login and registration.  You can guess what the purpose is.  The user is supposed to be able to request registration by clicking the registration link - which is a form with a submit button that does some database calls to see if the user is existing and so forth. The login page uses a authentication cookie for verification.  I am using forms authentication - this is in my web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="30" path="/" defaultUrl="~/logon.aspx">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

Every time I do a http call to the registration page (ie by typing in http://localhost/registration.aspx - it redirects to the login page.

The global.asax.cs file has this in there - it's an authentication check.  I want to disable this check if the requesting page is the registration page - since users do not need to be authenticated to visit this page.  Any ideas how to do this?

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    if (null == authCookie)
    {
        //There is no authentication cookie.
        return; // right here it will return null then redirect to login.aspx
    }
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
    try
    {
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Write the exception to the Event Log.
        return;
    }
    if (null == authTicket)
    {
        //Cookie failed to decrypt.
        return;
    }
    //When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
    //pipe-delimited string of group names.
    string[] groups = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });
    //Create an Identity.
    GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");
    //This principal flows throughout the request.
    GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, groups);
    Context.User = principal;
}
```

Comment: Can you check by string comparison if the URL of request contains substring 'registration" and not return ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628445/allow-access-for-unathenticated-users-to-specific-page-using-asp-net-forms-authe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure access in your web.config.  Here's an example of what I would do:

```
<location path="register.aspx"> //path here is path to your register.aspx
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: My pleasure!  Also, as an aside, @Sanjay has provided a nice link that describes its many uses, including modifying access at a folder level. What this means, is that you could group all registration-related pages into a single registration directory and provide access to that directory much the same way you would on a per-page basis. With that in mind, I usually place all of my pages (except for default.aspx) into a Pages directory, and secure the whole folder without restricting access to the home page (default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

it may help you
set it with web.config

```
 <location path="registration.aspx">
            <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users ="*" />
            </authorization>
            </system.web>
            </location>
```

More info MSDN Link  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871