# asp to aspx creates redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp-classic

I've been trying to solve that for few days but had no luck...
Two simple pages one of the is asp.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
</head>
 <body>
     <%
        response.write("KABOOM!")
        Response.Redirect ("http://boom.com:9800/login/aspx.aspx")

    %>

</body>
</html>
```

The other one is aspx.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO" %>
     <script runat="server">
         private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                  Response.Write("Page2 loaded !!!! ");
            }  
       </script>
```

It fails to redirect showing this:

[image]

I just can't understand what is wrong. Could someone please explain to me why is it not redirecting and should it redirect at all? May be it's me who is doing something wrong (I haven't used asp or asp.net before so it is absolutely possible..)

Thanks

Comment: Consider using global.asax to re-route asp to aspx

Comment: I don't have access to the route folder it's not on local machine..Poop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if you are already on the same page - and if yes, not redirect, here is an example:

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("aspx.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       Response.Redirect("aspx.aspx");
```

Now on classic asp the redirect is done as:

```
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location","http://example.com/page.aspx"
    Response.End
```

There is a case, because you have the login page, a user that is not authorized to hit the redirect loop because you do **not allow him to view the login page it self**. The login page must be available to the public.

On how you do that read this [Allow access for unathenticated users to specific page using ASP.Net Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628445/allow-access-for-unathenticated-users-to-specific-page-using-asp-net-forms-authe)

Comment: @Dims Check this: allow login page to been view by unauthorize users. Also found using the browser tools, what is the page that make the redirect to itself.

Comment: Authorization worked!!! AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!! Finally!!!!!! Thank you thank you thank you !!!!!!!!