# how to deny the users to access the particular url's. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to deny the access for anyone that uses an specific url.

For example:

The user can acces to: testing.com
but the user should not have access to: testing.com/files (even if the user paste this link in the url)

I tried using a Web.config, Global.asax file, but I'm unable to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <location path="http://mypath.com/files">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*"/>               
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I created both the Web.config and the Global.asax by hand because when I created the project they were not included. If there is some way to do this without using them it would be better. But I don't know which would be the best way.

Can you give me a tip for where it goes the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628445/allow-access-for-unathenticated-users-to-specific-page-using-asp-net-forms-authe

Comment: If web.config is in your app root, try `<location path="/files">`.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a web config into the files folder. While you can try and mess around with a main web.config, I would keep things simple, and to secure a folder by folder, then just add a web.config to each folder. It just oh so much less complex.

So, for that folder, then you can now have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
            <allow roles="Portal" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So, now you don't have to worry about mess up of the URL - it simply the folder you drop in the web.config file.

Now, do keep in mind, that if you secure the folder this way, then users's url's to files in that folder can't be use.

HOWEVER code behind can!!! So, keep in mind that IIS securty ONLY applies to your markup, url's and hyperlinks.

But, code behind is still 100% free to use that path name. And in fact, your code behind for use of such files will NOT be using URL's, but plane jane full windows file path names anyway.

So, you can still say provide a grid view or some such to list out the files in that folder, and when the user clicks on a button (say to download such a file), then you  can read the file, and steam (send) it out to the browser for a download.

but, any URL to the above file folders will not work.